# Android Where Clause

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm trying to write email search application in android , I want to search like

```
select * from message where subject like '%email%' or fromlist like'%email%'
or displayname like '%email%' or tolist like '%email%' or cclist like '%email%'
or bcclist like '%email%' or replytolist like '%email%';
```

How to write a where clause in query method in android???

Answer (score 1):

You can use a Raw Query on SQLite

This is what i do:

```
public Cursor getFriendsCursorByNickName(String nickname) {
    String[] args = new String[1];
    args[0] = "%"+nickname+"%";
    Cursor friendLike = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM friends WHERE nickname like ?", args);
    friendLike.moveToFirst();
    return friendLike;
}
```

The stuff here is "?" inside the query so you can prepare conditions outside as "args" do
I hope this guide you ;)

Answer (score 0):

Use [SQLiteDatabase.query](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#query%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5b%5d,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5b%5d,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) like this:

```
final String emailArg = "%" + email + "%";
final String where = "subject like ? OR fromlist like ?";
final String[] arguments = new String[] {
  emailArg,
  emailArg 
};

Cursor result = db.query("message", null, where, arguments, null, null, null, null);
```

You can then use the result as you want.